# Where can I find the Tab Bar Controller Class?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uitabbarcontroller

I wanted one of my tabs to open the camera when clicked - similar to instagram. I was told that I should override the function of the tab bar by making a subclass of the tab bar controller. However, I can't find where the superior class is. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController class inherits from [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController). You can check the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/):

> The UITabBarController class implements a specialized view controller
>   that manages a radio-style selection interface. This tab bar interface
>   displays tabs at the bottom of the window for selecting between the
>   different modes and for displaying the views for that mode. This class
>   is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.

Comment: How do I make a subclass?